# How to take screenshots showing the tooltip of an item?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I just tried taking a screenshot to show off my Endless Halloween Tonic to my friends (<300 ToT bags - lucky me).

I realized however, that the tooltip doesn't appear in the screenshot even though my mouse is hovering over it when the screenshot was taken.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: How are you taking the screenshot?

Comment: I ended up using Fraps or Overwolf to take these screenshots.

Comment: if your friends are in game you can Shift-click an item to add a link to it in chat. They can hover over it and see the stats.

Comment: @DavidYell Wanna expand that into an answer so I can upvote/accept? I don't think there is a way to currently just screenshot it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way that I've been able to achieve this is using a secondary program to take the screenshots.

There are three which I use regularly.
[Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) - This one you have to pay for but is pretty good and rather seemless.
[Overwolf](http://www.overwolf.com/) - A game overlay which is free and will take reasonably good screenshots for you.
[Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/) - If you create a shortcut to the game in your Steam client, you can then press F12 to take a screenshot, but you'll have to run the game from Steam.

Comment: I just found out if you use Puush and played in windowed mode, it works too? http://puu.sh/1t0gh

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without the use of a secondary program. Follow these steps:

1. Set your game to Windowed mode
2. Have another program open, like Calculator
3. Switch to Calculator and drag the program window to the bottom corner of your desktop to get it out of the screenshot
4. Switch back to GW2 and hover your mouse over the item in question
5. Alt+tab back to Calculator and do not move your mouse
6. Hit the Print Screen button
7. Open up Paint and paste

Essentially what this does is take a screenshot of your current windows desktop, which just happens to have GW2 in the frame. You will need to crop your start bar out of the picture, but it's a way to get what you're after without the need to install additional programs.

Comment: Does this technique work with full screen window mode also?